# Git: cannot push project to my server using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, terminal, ssh-keys, osx-server

**This is what I have done in my server (iMac):**

- I have made "repo" directory, to contain all my .git projects.
- I made it the current directory and used these commands in terminal:
  >

> $ mkdir test.git
>
> $ cd test.git
>
> $ git init --bare
>   
>   **This is what I have done in the client computer (MacBook):**

- I have exported .pub file and added it in the server to be able to connect using ssh.
- I have tested the connection using the following command:

  > $ ssh 192.168.1.1
- The MacBook was able to connect to the server perfectly.
- I used these commands in terminal:

  > $ cd project.git
  >
  > $ git remote add origin ssh://192.168.1.1:~/repo/test.git
  >
  > $ git push --all
- I got this message:

  > fatal: '/repo/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
  >
  > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  >
  > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  >
  > and the repository exists.

Comment: did you add something to git repo and commit it?

Comment: try with `git remote add origin user@192.168.1.1:~/repo/test.git`

Comment: @Jayan I have a local project and I want to push it to the server. I don't want to commit directly from the repo.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar I have tried that. didn't work

Comment: another suggestion: provide absolute path of test.git and check again.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar I didn't understand. please explain what you mean

Comment: I am not sure whether `/Documents/Server/repo/test.git` is correct path. Shouldn't it be like `/Users/<username>/Documents/Server/repo/test.git`?
If so, use full path in git remote url.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar I have edited the question. the path in the error was '/repo/test.git' not the one I added before. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!

the mistake was in this line:

> $ git remote add origin ssh://192.168.1.1:~/repo/test.git

the tilde (~) was causing the problem. Removing it makes everything work perfectly!